# multi column searching datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have datatables of serverside. I had problems with multiple column searching,all column work,if i search only one by one column.but if i multi column for searching,filter didn't work.example.if i search only "name" filter work,and if i search only one start_date filter work too.but if i search name and date simultaneously.filter didn't work .
so here my code:

```js
//my script: 
var table = $('#dataTables');

 // begin first table
    table.dataTable({

    "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo site_url('leader') ?>",
            "type": "POST",
            "data": function(d) {
            d.full_name = $('#full_name').val(); 
            d.start_date = $('#start_date').val(); //whats right code?
            d.end_date = $('#end_date').val(); //whats right code?
                      
            },
            },
      .....
      .....
      $('#btn-search').click(function(){
            var data_tables  =         $('#dataTables').DataTable();
            data_tables
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        })
```

```html
<!-- my view: -->
<div class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="full_name" class="form-control" id="full_name" placeholder="Name"/>
</div>
                    
<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group date date-picker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <input type="text" name="start_date" class="form-control" readonly id="start_date" size="8">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn default" type="button">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </button>
    </span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group date date-picker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
<input type="text" name="end_date" class="form-control" readonly id="end_date" size="8">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="btn default" type="button">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
</button>
</span>
</div>
</div>
 <button class="btn btn-warning" id="btn-search">Search</button>
</div>
```

serverside:

```html
if ($full_name) 
  {
            $where = "And full_name = '$full_name'";
        }
        else if($start_date) 
        {
         $where = "And start_date >= to_date('$start_date','DD-MM-YYYY') ";
        }
        else if($end_date) 
        {
         $where = "And end_date <= to_date('$end_date','DD-MM-YYYY') ";
        }
        
        else
        {
         $where = " "; //how to combine 3 above
        }
```

how to create condition if i search multicolumn in datatables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your server side code needs a change
try something like this:

```
$where = "";
if (!empty($full_name))
{
    $where .= "And full_name = '$full_name' ";
}
if(!empty($start_date))
{
    $where .= "And start_date >= to_date('$start_date','DD-MM-YYYY') ";
}

if(!empty($end_date))
{
    $where = "And end_date <= to_date('$end_date','DD-MM-YYYY') ";
}
```

on a sidenote:
you tagged this question as a Codeigniter related question - whats the reason behind for not using the query builder? (your approach is a bit "unsecure"...)

Comment: i create above code in codeigniter,so many thank code worked.